# Entity Framework code first database for one to one to many association

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm building a database with entityframework using code first. The aim is to syncronize a remote database with webservice call. I already have a structured entities builded for webservice call function.

How do i need to code the dB context for create the following association ?

the cart.cs gives cart_row through AssociationsCartAux, as follow

```
public class order
{
    [Key]
    public long? id { get; set; }
    public long? id_cart { get; set; } //which is a foreign key
    public string invoice_number { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class cart
{
    public long? id { get; set; }
    ...
    public AssociationsCartAux associations { get; set; }
}

public class AssociationsCartAux : PrestaShopEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long? id_virtual { get; set; }
    public List<cart_row> cart_rows { get; set; }

    public AssociationsCartAux()
    {
        this.cart_rows = new List<cart_row>();
    }
}

public class cart_row
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long? id_cartRow_fictive { get; set; }
    public long? id_product { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

I tried the following code in my dbcontext file

```
    public DbSet<cart> cart { get; set; }
    public DbSet<cart_row> cart_row { get; set; }
    public DbSet<order> order { get; set; }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AssociationsCartAux>()
        .HasMany(p => p.cart_rows)
        .WithMany().Map(c =>
        {
            c.ToTable("cart_assocation");
        });
```

When i run the code, it's building the following tables

dbo.carts

dbo.cart_row

dbo.AssociationsCartAuxes

- id_virtual

dbo.cart_assocation <=== ASSOCIATION BETWEEN CART AND CART_ROW

- AssociationsCartAux_id_virtual
- cart_row_id_cartRow_fictive

when i reload the data syncronisation ==> no problem
when i reload the data syncronisation with an order update ==> 
the dbo.AssociationsCartAuxes double in volume additionnaly to the existing data, despite of update the current data and add only the new one. Involving the lost of the linq association between cart and cart_row. Which let me suppose that i don't have correctly build my dbcontext.

I'm not familiar with entity framework so i tried some way to do this with putting AssociationsCartAux.cs as a ComplexType but not work because of cart_row object inside.

Thanks you in advance for any help.

For additionnal information, i put the way how i put data into the tables

```
            foreach (cart panier in listcart)
            {
                var result = ctx.cart.SingleOrDefault(b => b.id == panier.id);
                if (result == null)
                {
                    ctx.cart.Add(panier);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

          foreach (order commande in listorder)
            {
                var result = ctx.order.SingleOrDefault(b => b.id == commande.id);
                if (result == null)
                {
                    ctx.order.Add(commande);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, may be it could help someone to make a such third level association. Simply add : 
modelBuilder.Entity().ToTable("carts");

to the db context as follow.

in the db context :

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<cart>()
            .HasRequired(s => s.associations)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.cart);

        modelBuilder.Entity<cart_row>()
            .HasRequired(cr => cr.AssociationsCartAux)
            .WithMany(c => c.cart_rows)
            .HasForeignKey(cr => cr.id_AssocCartAux);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AssociationsCartAux>().ToTable("carts"); <== this solved my issue
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an auxiliar table for a one-to-many relationship, it's enough with:

```
public class cart
{
    public long? id { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<cart_row> cart_rows { get; set; }
}
```

And the magic of EF will do the rest, although it's a good idea to explicitly define the relationship in the other end as well:

```
public class cart_row
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long? id_cartRow_fictive { get; set; }
    public long? id_product { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    ....
    public long? id_cart {get; set;}
    public cart cart {get; set;}
}
```

And in the DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<cart_row>()
            .HasOne(cr => cr.cart)
            .WithMany(c => c.cart_rows)
            .HasForeignKey(cr => cr.id_cart);
    }
```

But there are many other ways in which you can achieve this, for more information check:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Comment: Thanks Coder cat, if only it was as simple as you say ^^. I must use this entities relation because the architecture is made to perform webservice call. I can access cart_row data only through AssociationsCartAuxes. I'm simply perform a add cart after a xwebservice call and cart_row fill automatically to the database via associationCartAuxes. So i unfortunately can't modify the relation architecture.